# Using pytest to test max_length of django model field

Tags: django, database, pytest

I'm doing some scraping of several webpages and storing the information into a django model.

I recently discovered the `max_length` that I had considered for some fields was not long enough so I had to increase it.

In order to make sure nobody in our team nobody is using a old version of the model, nor in production, we wanted to prepare a few simple tests with pytest.

Lets consider the following excerpt of the model

```
class JobOffer(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100) # this should be 120
```

Now, I try to make a test that fails when we store a string longer than 100 chars.

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_joboffer_title_length(self):
    lots = 'x'*120
    JobOffer.objects.create(title=lots)
```

When I run, **this test passes**. However, when I execute **the same command in the shell** it **rises a DatabaseError**

What could be the reason of that behavior? Does pytest consider the `max_length` of the fields?

Comment: How are you executing those tests? You mention "When I run, this test passes", and "when I execute the same command in the shell", what those commands are exactly?

Comment: What I meant is that when I execute the test as shown it fails. However when I run the command inside it ( ```JobOffer.objects.create(title=x'*120)``` ) in the shell, it rises an error

Comment: @kiril Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

A late answer but I hope to be useful for further reader.
[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) refer to this:

> Note that full_clean() will not be called automatically when you call your model’s save() method. You’ll need to call it manually when you want to run one-step model validation for your own manually created model

Try next solution

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_joboffer_title_length(self):
    lots = 'x'*120
    job_offer = JobOffer(title=lots)
    job_offer.full_clean()
```

This will fail with ValidationError. Next code could be useful for checking if exception is raised when exceed max length:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_joboffer_title_length(self):
    lots = 'x'*120
    job_offer = JobOffer(title=lots)
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        job_offer.full_clean()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to `save()` the object you're creating, as that's when the constraints are evaluated:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_joboffer_title_length(self):
    lots = 'x'*120
    JobOffer.objects.create(title=lots).save()
```

Now that test should fail.

Comment: The create method is a shortcut to using the constructor then calling `save`. This makes no difference.